# Heroku commands not working on Windows

Tags: windows, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

For any Heroku command on Windows, I get the following error:

```
!  Unable to connect to Heroku API, check internet connectivity...
```

None of the commands like `heroku login`, `status`, `update`, etc. work. They give the same error message.
OS is Windows 8.1

Comment: are you sure you have internet connectivity ? the proper address to the `Heroku` server ? no firewall or antivirus interfering ?

Comment: Yes. Disabled the firewall. No anti-virus interfering. The heroku website is working just fine. But, via command line, it gives the error.

Comment: Hi @AtulDubey, did you solve it?